# Multidimensional array calculations in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [field_value] => Green
                            [ordering] => 0
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [field_value] => Red
                            [ordering] => 1
                            [count] => 0
                        )
                    ...
               )
          )
     [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [field_value] => Metall
                            [ordering] => 0
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [field_value] => Plastic
                            [ordering] => 1
                            [count] => 0
                        )
                    ...
               )
          )
)
```

**Second array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 3
)
```

And I would like to get output array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [field_value] => Green
                            [ordering] => 0
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [field_value] => Red
                            [ordering] => 1
                            [count] => 6
                        )
                    ...
               )
          )
     [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [field_value] => Metall
                            [ordering] => 0
                            [count] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [field_value] => Plastic
                            [ordering] => 1
                            [count] => 3
                        )
                    ...
               )
          )
)
```

How can I do this using `array_map()` or `array_walk_recursive()` functions?

Comment: And what have you done so far ?

Comment: Hi there. On a number of occasions the community has discussed whether home-made tag devices belong in titles, and the result was that they do not (mainly since we already have a tagging system). If you can write titles as an ordinary question in English, that is ideal.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far?